# Wordpress include("../../../wp-blog-header"); failing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a plugin for Wordpress involving lots of .php files. I see that for my AddShift.php file, we are successfully importing the blog header using the following line of code:

```
include("../../../wp-blog-header.php");
```

However, when I try to do the same thing in my ajax_cal_split.php file, I get the following error:

```
Warning: include(./wp-blog-header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog/wp-content/plugins/Shifty/ajax_cal_split.php on line 11

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening './wp-blog-header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog/wp-content/plugins/Shifty/ajax_cal_split.php on line 11
```

Line 11 of course says

```
include("../../../wp-blog-header.php");
```

Is there any reason for this call to work on one .php file and not another, when they reside in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - I believe wordpress operates a security mechanism on content in the wp-content directory, I had the same problem with themes. The workaround I used was to include with absolute path names.

Comment: hrmm... I tried that, but I get the same issue... Trying it again real fast.

Doing this gives me:
http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog/wp-content/plugins/Shifty/ajax_cal_split.php on line 11

Comment: allow_url_include is a php setting, I have mine set to Off in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (ubuntu)... not sure what's going on there! Seems like it should work. When you use absolute paths are you doing that with the file system /opt/lampp/... or http://....?

Comment: You can't have a `http://` in your absolute path. Your absolute path should look like this: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog`

Comment: Second pekka - unless you enable allow_url_include, which you don't want to do for security reasons. Sorry, I should have said filesystem.

Comment: Hrmm... This gets rid of the initial errors, but I'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_option() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/sandboxj/blog/wp-content/plugins/Shifty/ajax_cal_split.php on line 243 now when I call the ajax functions for ajax_cal_split ....

Comment: That must be some inherent problem in your file (e.g. a missing include somewhere), it has nothing to do with the include I believe.

Comment: Is there something specific I need to have for get_option then?

Comment: Solution is just below, from Keshav Kalra

Answer (score 7):

This is your solution to get the real path in plugin file

```
<?php
$scriptPath = dirname(__FILE__);
 $path = realpath($scriptPath . '/./');
 $filepath = explode("wp-content",$path);
// print_r($filepath);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require(''.$filepath[0].'/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Comment: +1 Don't know why this answer was not accepted when in fact, it solves the problem.

Comment: You are right Devner, This answer should be accepted , it solved the problem.

Comment: But instead of using split function , Use explode function because split method is already deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the WP_PLUGIN_URL constant provided by wordpress. For example, you can define you actual plugin url like this:

```
define('MyPLUGIN_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/plugin_folder/');
```

and then use it in your calls like:

```
include(MyPLUGIN_URL."wp-blog-header.php");
```

Thats how i solve the problem, sorry for late answer but it might help the next ones checking in.

Answer (score 0):

it works, do as suggested and use an absolute url, i used

include("wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/DESIRED_FILE.php");