# PHP/AJAX only works when something gets echoed?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to include the Wordpress blog header in a php file to use it as an AJAX call function.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES',false);

echo 'Something';

require(explode("wp-content",realpath(dirname(__FILE__)))[0].'wp-blog-header.php');
```

*Original snippet found in: [Wordpress include("../../../wp-blog-header"); failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157604/wordpress-include-wp-blog-header-failing), current by Ole Sauffaus.*

The code only works when there is something echoed or printed between the `define` and the `require` function. Without it the server responds with a 404-error.

This behavior occurs only when I target the php via an AJAX request as follows.

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('directory_results').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8888/appsconnected/wp-content/themes/appsconnected/ajax-loop.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("platform=" + platforms + "&category=" + category + "&orderby=" + order);
```

What causes this behavior?

Comment: You lack a '.' in the `$path`-assigment i believe

Comment: There are some pretty strange code artefacts in this: `$scriptPath . '/./'`... what is the `/./` for here? Also `''.$filepath[0].'/wp-blog-header.php`... what is the `''.` for?

Comment: I'm not really sure what they're for. As mentioned, I found this code as an answer on another question about getting the wp-blog-header. But echoing or printing something shouldn't have any effect on the surrounding code right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

    define('WP_USE_THEMES',false);
    require(explode("wp-content",realpath(dirname(__FILE__)))[0].'wp-blog-header.php');

?>
```

Comment: But here's the weird part: if I echo anything between the `define` and `require` it does work.

Comment: That sounds really weird ... I have no explanation!

Comment: Could it have to do with the fact that I'm trying to run this php file via AJAX? I will post my JavaScript XMLHttpRequest in an edit.

Comment: No ... php doesn’t care how it is called ... and your server should just execute when requested ...

Comment: The path in the JavaScript is correct. I'm not sure about the path in the require, but it responds with 404 when not found (and apparently when found & without a random echo). However I can use wordpress functions thus it has to be correct (when I echo something).

Comment: You need to be sure that the require-path is correct ... it is that simple ... otherwise this is waste of time.

Comment: If the require path is incorrect I wouldn't be able to use Wordpress' functions. I can use WP's functions when I use your code with an `echo` in between, thus it has to be correct.

Comment: That is guessing ... not checking ... check it!

Comment: If I use the absolute path, the same problem occurs. The require only works when it is preceded with a echo or print command. If I open the php file without targeting it via AJAX, it works without the echo..

Comment: Try to replace your `echo` with this: `sleep(1);` ... does that work?

Comment: No.. It should have something to do with the AJAX part, don't you think? The php needs to set the `xmlhttp.responseText` to something before it will run the `require`.

Comment: I think your Ajax perhaps need a character-response to continue, and your `wp-blog-header.php` delivers nothing ... I don’t know ... perhaps you could just do: `echo ' ';` ... I'm out of ideas!

Comment: I guess so. I'm currently echoing `'<span style="display:none;"></span>"`. That way it doesn't mess up my site flow. Thanks for the help.