# Error when include wordpress header

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make a news section for my homepage "**index.php**". So I use ajax to load "**pages/news.php**"'s content into a news div in **index.php**. This **pages/news.php** is supposed to pull out latest posts and format them nicely. The blog is in **localhost:81/blog/**

When I view **localhost:81/pages/news.php**, it can display the posts, no errors. But when I run **localhost:81/index.php**, it said

> jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:81/pages/news.php 404 (Not
>   Found)

If I remove this line in pages/news.php:

```
include(dirname(__DIR__) . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php')
```

**index.php** won't have error, but of course cannot view the posts.
If I copy the code in **pages/news.php** to **index.php**, it works (of course with appropriate including path). I am very confused here, how come using the same code but retrieving **news.php** content from ajax does not work but **news.php** itself works?

Could someone please advise me what has gone wrong?

Thank you for your time reading.

Comment: did you try echo-ing "dirname(\_\_DIR__) . '/blog/wp-blog-header.php'" on the ajax call ?

Comment: I suggest reading this thread first, as it may point you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157604/wordpress-include-wp-blog-header-failing

Comment: Hi Random, the return is C:\Website 2016\trunk\website/blog/wp-blog-header.php where C:\Website 2016\trunk\website is the root folder

Comment: Hi TodorS, thanks for the link but I don't really get it..

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this is a common issue: wordpress forces user to use ajax in a specific way. The instruction is here: http://rocketpopmedia.com/discover/2013/06/21/wordpress-ajax-and-the-404-error-youre-receiving/