# Failed to open stream Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am unable to access my admin dashboard. Keep facing this error

> Warning: require(/home/****/****/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/zicolaw/zico_group/wp-admin/index.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/****/****/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   /home/zicolaw/zico_group/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

So I checked my Index.php and tried to fix this problem by changing to the path from /wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php to /mysite/wp-blog-header.php but the result is still same.

This is index.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */@include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-includes/js/utilities.js' );

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Also, I had my backup from 2 months ago, and I compare both Index.php files.The current Index.php in website is quite different than old one. So what I did is just replacing them but after 5 sec later, it changes the old code like above.
Is there any way to change it?

Thank you

Comment: [Wordpress include(“../../../wp-blog-header”); failing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2157619/4248328)

Comment: Meanwhile you can check manually type echo into  wp-blog-header.php and index.php . and if possible upload same file again and see what happens.let me know as well.

Comment: Rushil and Alive I have seen those post but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Ash, I am sorry but I do not understand what you meant.

Comment: plz upload wp-blog-header.php and index.php of root file again..

Comment: you need to update your .htaccess file if you are uploading wordpress application into sub folder

Comment: Yes, I have reupload the files but after 5 secs later It changes to old one. Until last Saturday I did not have the same issue. I do not how that had happened.

Comment: _“This is index.php code”_ - that is from the index.php on the root level; your error messages are referring to what the index.php inside the `wp-admin` folder is trying to embed. And the latter should not try to require `wp-blog-header.php` to begin with, that just makes no sense.

Comment: Is this a type of attack or malicious that messed up with the website?